# How do you locate the .sln Report file from which a rdl file was deployed (only having the deployed file on the server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdl

We have a server full of (.sln) report projects each containing anywhere from 5 to 40 or so rdl files. We have Visual studio with about 15 Projects we are aware of, probably more hidden elsewhere (Created by users over time).

Generally they are designed by grouping. I.e. Marketing Reports go into the marketing folder, Ticketing reports go into ticketing folder etc.

When we query

```
SELECT      Ds.Name as Data_Source_Name,
            C2.Name AS Data_Source_Reference_Name,
            C.Name AS Dependent_Item_Name,
            C.Path AS Dependent_Item_Path
FROM        ReportServer.dbo.DataSource AS DS
INNER JOIN  ReportServer.dbo.Catalog AS C ON DS.ItemID = C.ItemID AND DS.Link IN (
                                                                SELECT ItemID 
                                                                FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
                                                                WHERE Type = 2) --Type 5 identifies data sources
FULL OUTER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C2 ON DS.Link = C2.ItemID
WHERE       C2.Type = 2
ORDER BY    C.Path,
            C2.Name ASC,
            C.Name ASC;
```

or even simpler

```
SELECT      C.Name AS Dependent_Item_Name,
            C.Path AS Dependent_Item_Path
FROM        ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
WHERE       C.Type = 2
```

we are able to locate the deployed file with the above code - but this doesn't help us. We need to find the project where it was created (the .sln project) to find the file to be able to edit.

The file itself lives directly (on main level) of server directory. `/Reports` folder. Which is entirely unhelpful. I am not sure where to look in the set up (even though I've looked all over) in an effort to find the project from which this rdl files was deployed.

We started clicking around from project to project but there are so many and we aren't finding it.

Any coding tips or searching tips would be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, you will not find .rptproj meta-data in the ssrs database. Also, you don't even need a VS project to upload .rdl files  (think ssrs upload and Report Builder). If you are sure they came from a VS project then you may want to visit your source control repository.

Comment: @RossBush thank you, i was not aware (somewhat novice with ssrs) that you don't need a project. We still need to find the file it must have been created somewhere, we need to be able to edit it (add data/format etc). Not sure the best way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried find in files? The report name should be the same in the .rptproj file.

Comment: do you mean just do a search for the filename.rptproj file in the file explorer. Yes, I tried (the problem is that I think we have so many directories I'm scared I may not be looking for it in the right place)